# FlowRouter no longer working after Meteor + React deployment using Mupx

Tags: meteor, reactjs, deployment, flow-router, meteor-up

I have a Meteor + React app that works fine locally. I've tested using the --production flag and there are no issues.

Once I use mupx to deploy to my server, the deployment is successful but when I go to the deployed app it throws "There is no route for the path: /".

My routes.js file is located in the client directory.

Here is my mupx logs -f result

> npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important
>   features, npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the
>   primary npm npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at
>   least npm@2, if not the npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To
>   upgrade to npm@2, run: npm WARN deprecated  npm WARN deprecated npm -g
>   install npm@latest-2 npm WARN deprecated  npm WARN deprecated To
>   upgrade to the latest stable version, run: npm WARN deprecated  npm
>   WARN deprecated npm -g install npm@latest npm WARN deprecated  npm
>   WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your
>   system, you npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding
>   commands with sudo, or if npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them
>   from an Administrator prompt.) npm WARN deprecated  npm WARN
>   deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with npm WARN
>   deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10
>   LTS npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which
>   has some small npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made
>   to npm run-script and npm WARN deprecated semver behavior. npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN
>   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
>
> fibers@1.0.8 install
>   /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers node build.js ||
>   nodejs build.js make: Entering directory
>   /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build' CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers/src/coroutine.o CC(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers/src/libcoro/coro.o SOLINK_MODULE(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers.node SOLINK_MODULE(target)
>   Release/obj.target/fibers.node: Finished COPY Release/fibers.node
>   make: Leaving
>   directory/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build'
>   Installed in
>   /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node
>   npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js
>   (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server) ansi-regex@0.2.1
>   node_modules/ansi-regex
>
> ansi-styles@1.1.0 node_modules/ansi-styles
>
> escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 node_modules/escape-string-regexp
>
> chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
>
> has-ansi@0.1.0 node_modules/has-ansi
>
> strip-ansi@0.3.0 node_modules/strip-ansi
>
> supports-color@0.2.0 node_modules/supports-color
>
> eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
>
> type-of@2.0.1 node_modules/type-of
>
> amdefine@1.0.0 node_modules/amdefine
>
> asap@2.0.3 node_modules/asap
>
> underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore
>
> meteor-promise@0.5.1 node_modules/meteor-promise
>
> promise@7.0.4 node_modules/promise
>
> source-map-support@0.3.2 node_modules/source-map-support
>
> semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver
>
> source-map@0.1.32 node_modules/source-map
>
> fibers@1.0.8 node_modules/fibers
>   => Starting meteor app on port:80

Comment: Do you have any error before that `There is no route for the path...`?

Comment: @Gemmi no there is no error before that.

Comment: I don't know your exact files structure but people will often put some React code directly into `routes.jsx` because of how the `mount()` helper works. Is it possible that this file is not properly interpreted during the build process?

Comment: You can also try running `meteor build ...` locally and then run your app "from bundle". It will be easier to debug this way.

Comment: @apendua I guess theoretically it could be an issue such as it's not interpreted during the build process, but I'm unsure how how to test that?